# OpenCL pipes on intel CPU

Tags: opencl, cpu, intel, fpga, opencl-pipes

I am working on my dissertation project trying to investigate if and when the use of OpenCL pipes can be useful also on CPUs (we already know they are widely used in FPGAs).

I am trying to implement even the simplest algorithm where I have a producer (writing to the pipe) and a consumer kernel (reading from the pipe). I would like to execute the two kernels in parallel and have a blocking behaviour for the pipe (read only when the pipe is not empty). Reading on Intel documentation at [Intel_FPGA_Opencl](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/documentation/mwh1391807965224.html#ewa1426013362278) it is explained that the attribute `__attribute__((blocking))` declared for the pipe should have the read operation blocking when the pipe is empty. However, when I try to use the attribute I get `__write_pipe_2_bl is undefined`. I even tried to emulate the blocking behaviour with a while loop (as shown in the intel documentation) but the kernel stalls even if the pipe is not empty.

Furthermore, the kernels seem not to run in parallel unless I use two different command queues.

Kernel code:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_intel_printf : enable
#define SIZE 1000

__kernel void pipe_writer(__global int *in,
                          write_only pipe int __attribute((depth(SIZE))) p)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        write_pipe(p, &in[i]);
        printf("written: %d\n", in[i]);
    }

}

__kernel void pipe_reader(__global int *out,
                          read_only pipe int __attribute((depth(SIZE))) p)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        while (read_pipe(p, &out[i]) == -1){
        //printf("blocked read\n";
        }
        //int check = read_pipe(p, &out[i]);
        printf("read: %d\n", out[i]);
    }
}
```

Host Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

int main(void) {
    // Create the two input vectors
    int bb = 0;
    int i;
    const int LIST_SIZE = 1000;
    int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    int *B = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = i;
    }

    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("getPlatformId, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1,
            &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("getDevice, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("createContext, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }
    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
    cl_command_queue command_queue2 = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("commandQueue, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem a_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem b_mem_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);

    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("memobj, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, a_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), A, 0, NULL, NULL);

    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("enqueuewritebuffer, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
            (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("crateProgWithSource, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "-cl-std=CL2.0", NULL, NULL);

    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("buildProgram, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    /////Debug Kernel compilation:
    size_t ret_val_size;
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &ret_val_size);
    char * build_log = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (ret_val_size));
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, ret_val_size, build_log, NULL);
    printf("LOG: \n%s\n", build_log);
    ///////////////////////////////

    cl_kernel pipe_writer = clCreateKernel(program, "pipe_writer", &ret);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("createkernelwriter, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    cl_kernel pipe_reader = clCreateKernel(program, "pipe_reader", &ret);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("createkernelReader, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    cl_mem pipe = clCreatePipe(context, 0, sizeof(cl_int), 1000, NULL, &ret);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("createPipe, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(pipe_writer, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("setArgWriterZERO, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(pipe_writer, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &pipe);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("setArgWriterONE, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(pipe_reader, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("setArgReaderZERO, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(pipe_reader, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &pipe);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("setArgReaderONE, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = 1; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 1; // Divide work items into groups of 64

    cl_event sync; //??

    ret = clEnqueueTask (command_queue, pipe_writer, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("EnqueueKernelWriter, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("EnqueueKernelwriter, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clEnqueueTask (command_queue2, pipe_reader, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("EnqueueKernelWriter, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
        printf("EnqueueKernelReader, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        bb=1;
    }

    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue2, b_mem_obj, CL_TRUE, 0,
            LIST_SIZE * sizeof(int), B, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != CL_SUCCESS){
       printf("EnqueueReadBuffer, ERROR CODE: %d\n", ret);
       bb=1;
    }

    if(bb == 0){
    // Display the result to the screen
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d and %d\n", A[i], B[i]);
    }

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(pipe_writer);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(pipe_reader);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(a_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(A);
    free(B);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I get about the CPU I am using running 'clinfo':

```
Platform Name                                   Intel(R) CPU Runtime for OpenCL(TM) Applications
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2698 v4 @ 2.20GHz
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 2.1 (Build 0)
  Driver Version                                  18.1.0.0920
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 2.0 
  Device Type                                     CPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               80
  Max clock frequency                             2200MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     80
    Supported partition types                     by counts, equally, by names (Intel)
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             8192x8192x8192
  Max work group size                             8192
  Preferred work group size multiple              128
  Max sub-groups per work group                   1
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                 1 / 32      
    short                                                1 / 16      
    int                                                  1 / 8       
    long                                                 1 / 4       
    half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                1 / 8       
    double                                               1 / 4        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              540956721152 (503.8GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           135239180288 (126GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) capabilities        (core)
    Coarse-grained buffer sharing                 Yes
    Fine-grained buffer sharing                   Yes
    Fine-grained system sharing                   Yes
    Atomics                                       Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Preferred alignment for atomics                 
    SVM                                           64 bytes
    Global                                        64 bytes
    Local                                         0 bytes
  Max size for global variable                    65536 (64KiB)
  Preferred total size of global vars             65536 (64KiB)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        262144
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             480
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            8452448768 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   64 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          64 bytes
    Max 2D image size                             16384x16384 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             2048x2048x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 480
    Max number of write image args                480
    Max number of read/write image args           480
  Max number of pipe args                         16
  Max active pipe reservations                    3276
  Max pipe packet size                            1024
  Local memory type                               Global
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        131072 (128KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     480
  Max size of kernel argument                     3840 (3.75KiB)
  Queue properties (on host)                      
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Local thread execution (Intel)                Yes
  Queue properties (on device)                    
    Out-of-order execution                        Yes
    Profiling                                     Yes
    Preferred size                                4294967295 (4GiB)
    Max size                                      4294967295 (4GiB)
  Max queues on device                            4294967295
  Max events on device                            4294967295
  Prefer user sync for interop                    No
  Profiling timer resolution                      1ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
    Sub-group independent forward progress        No
    IL version                                    SPIR-V_1.0
    SPIR versions                                 1.2
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_icd cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_spir cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_intel_vec_len_hint
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenCL 2.0 Pipes used for Intel FPGA are quite different from the
standard OpenCL 2.0 used for CPU.

One important difference is that standard OpenCL 2.0 Pipes are *not*
meant to be used to establish a communication between concurrent
kernels. Pipes are a subclass of memory objects and their state is
enforced only at a syncronization point (see s3.3.1 Memory Consistency
of OpenCL 1.2 Specification), where syncronization point is either a
command queue barrier, or a wait on event (see s3.4.3
Synchronization). In other words, according to the OpenCL
Specification, data written to a pipe is only visible when the kernel
finishes execution.

Intel OpenCL for FPGA have additional features (extensions) to make
OpenCL 2.0 Pipes usable for FPGA: specifically, it guarantess that
kernels can communicate over pipes, and provides a few extensions to
make such communication simpler and more efficient (blocking pipes,
host pipes, pipe depth). All these features are not supported by
Intel OpenCL runtime for CPU.

However, for the purpose of your dissertation project, you can look at
the Fast Emulator from Intel FPGA SDK: basically it is a CPU runtime
that supports FPGA extensions, including pipes (with kernel-to-kernel communication) and host pipes. See
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/opencl-sdk/aocl_programming_guide.pdf
s8.7. Using the Fast Emulator (Preview).

> Furthermore, the kernels seem not to run in parallel unless I use two different command queues.

If you don't create a command queue with
`CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE`, a queue is in-order, meaning
that there is an implicit dependency between commands pushed to this
queue, so they cannot run in parallel.

Also, you should call `clFlush(command_queue)` before
`clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue2, ...)` to ensure that the writer
kernel is started before you make a blocking call for the reader.

Comment: Maybe you know better, but this is from the book Heterogenous Computing with OpenCL 2.0: "For some applications, the producer and consumer can operate concurrently, with the consumer processing data as it is generated by the producer. OpenCL 2.0 has introduced pipe memory objects to facilitate producer-consumer applications. Pipes have the potential to offer utility regardless of **whether or not the producer-consumer kernels execute serially or concurrently**."